# Stopping Amazon WorkDocs syncing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-workdocs

I accidentally moved a folder containing a large number of files into my Amazon WorkDocs folder on the AWS Workspace.  I have removed the folder but WorkDocs is still syncing pushing the files to the sync'ed directory.  Is there a way to stop the transfer of files or do I have to wait until its finished?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my problem.  I clicked the WorkDocs icon in the system tray, selected settings a selected 'files and folders to sync'.  I then de-selected the folder that was causing the problem and it then stopped syncing that folder.